# Selecting the opposite to the results returned by query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to simplify my code.

I currently have two querys: one selecting the list of information and outputing it with select boxes to add to a users subscriptions then a second query to select the items that user already has subscribed but I am trying to simplify the code to one query.

I can currently get the code to display the options that the user has subscribed to with check boxes but not the opposite is there a way to select the opposite to the results in a WHERE clause?

```
$selectionQuery = 'SELECT t1.subId, t1.subTitle FROM tbl_subs t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_list t2 ON t2.subId = t1.subId WHERE t2.userId = '.$id.' AND t1.subId = t2.subId';
```

Comment: From the DB perspective, it seems more effective to first retrieve all possible topic subID's separately and then use the output of your query and that list to calculate the opposite. Also, I believe you don't need LEFT JOIN. Using JOIN should be more effective.

Comment: So it is best to use two query's then cross check the two outputs to find the opposite?

Comment: If you are going to do a lot of these "negative queries" and your topics aren't changing in the realtime, then yes, because the first query you do only once, and the "positive" query is quicker to do than the "negative" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code maybe is not ansiSQL but it works perfect on MYSQL.

$selectionQuery = 'SELECT t1.subId, t1.subTitle FROM tbl_subs as t1 WHERE not exists (select 1 from tbl_list as t2 where t2.userId = '.$id.' AND t1.subId = t2.subId)';

Comment: This method worked perfectly. Just to clarify you basically ask the original query to check against another query for records that don't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You already joining the subId at the `LEFT JOIN` part. Remove the `AND t1.subId = t2.subId'` from the `WHERE` part, as it joins again your resultset and overcomes the left join.

Correct:

```
$selectionQuery = 'SELECT t1.subId, t1.subTitle FROM tbl_subs t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_list t2 ON t2.subId = t1.subId WHERE t2.userId = '.$id.';
```